# R - Efficient way to apply function on all features grouped using plyr

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

Let `df`be our test data frame:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3),
                 var1 = round(runif(7)),
                 var2 = round(runif(7)),
                 var3 = round(runif(7)))
df

  id var1 var2 var3
1  1    0    1    1
2  1    0    1    0
3  2    1    0    1
4  2    1    0    1
5  3    0    0    0
6  3    1    1    1
7  3    1    0    1
```

I want to summarize over the id and sum up all values like this:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(sum_var_1 = sum(var1),
            sum_var_2 = sum(var2),
            sum_var_3 = sum(var3)) %>% 
  data.frame

  id sum_var_1 sum_var_2 sum_var_3
1  1         0         2         1
2  2         2         0         2
3  3         2         1         2
```

Now the question: Is there a way to avoid the `sum_var_2 = sum(var2) [...]` step and do it functionally inside the `summarise` with something like a formula or so? As there a hundreds of features I'd like to sum up!

Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since all your variables start with "*var*" you can do

```
df %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% 
   summarise_at(vars(starts_with("var")), sum)
```

which returns your example.

Edit: As @jake-kaupp commented, `summarise_all` does the job even better and also does not require the variable names to be normalized:

```
df %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% 
   summarise_all(sum)
```

Comment: You can also use `summarise_all` which will summarize everything except the grouping variables.